# How to Draw rectangle using rectangle function OpenGL in visual Basic

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graphics

using rectangle function how i draw a rectangle in openGL in the platform of visual basic

Comment: Do you want to know how to draw a rectangle using C++ or Visual Basic?

Comment: yes please.@ThomasMatthews

Comment: Which language, C++ **or** Visual Basic?  If you don't know the difference between the languages, you should take some time off and learn both languages.

Comment: Thanks for your information. i just trying to draw  rectangle using rectangle function to openGL in visual stdio using C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples of this function on the internet. Here is the template for the rectangle function.

```
void WINAPI glRectd(
   GLdouble x1,
   GLdouble y1,
   GLdouble x2,
   GLdouble y2
);
```

Parameters

x1

```
The x coordinate of the vertex of a rectangle.
```

y1

```
The y coordinate of the vertex of a rectangle.
```

x2

```
The x coordinate of the opposite vertex of the rectangle.
```

y2

```
The y coordinate of the opposite vertex of the rectangle.
```

More examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/OpenGL/glrect-functions